# error while calling stored procedure through jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

below is my jsp program which is not executing properly.It is directly returning exception error message.jdbc connections are there in include file.here batchcode and ccode are composite key.program should first check whether these are already inserted into database or not and then it should insert.

```
procedure:
create or replace procedure udp_addbatch(
p_batchcode  varchar2,
p_ccode  varchar2
)
as 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO BATCHES(BATCHCODE,CCODE) VALUES(p_batchcode,p_ccode);
commit;
END ;
/

**jsp file**

        <html>
<%@page import="java.sql.*, java.lang.String" %>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
input{
     FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; FONT-SIZE:10pt; color:blue;
}
body{ 
    FONT-FAMILY:Verdana;
    FONT-SIZE:10pt;
    FONT-WEIGHT:Bold;
    }
table{
    FONT-FAMILY:Verdana;
    FONT-SIZE:10pt;
    FONT-WEIGHT:Bold;
     }
H1,H2,H3{
    FONT-FAMILY:Verdana;
    FONT-SIZE:13pt;
    FONT-WEIGHT:Bold;
    COLOR:BLUE;
    }
SELECT {
        font-family : verdana; font-size : 9pt; background-color : #FCFCFC; border: 1px solid #000000; color:blue;
        } 
TEXTAREA { 
    font-family : verdana; font-size : 9pt; background-color : #FCFCFC; border: 1px solid #000000; color:blue;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<%@include file="jdbcresults.jsp"%>
<%


    ResultSet rs=null;
    int nr;
        CallableStatement cstmt=null;
    try
    {   


        String BatchCode=request.getParameter("BatchCode");
        String CCode=request.getParameter("CCode");

        cstmt=con.prepareCall("{call udp_addbatch(?,?)}");
                cstmt.setString(1,BatchCode);
                cstmt.setString(2,CCode);



                rs=cstmt.executeQuery("select * from Batches where CCode='"+CCode+"' and BatchCode='"+BatchCode+"'");
        if (!rs.next())
        {
            cstmt.executeUpdate();
            out.println("<h2 align='center'> Batch and course Successfully added</h2>");
        }
        else
            {
                            out.println("<h2 align='center'> Batch and Course already Exists</h2>");
               out.println("<center><a href='Addbatch.jsp'>Go Back</a></center>");
                }

         rs.close();
        cstmt.close();
         con.close();
    }



catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();} 
        out.print("<h2 align='center'>course doesn't exist");
                out.println("<center><a href='Addbatch.jsp'>Go Back</a></center>");
                }
finally{
        // The finally clause is always executed - even in error
        // conditions PreparedStatements and Connections will always be closed
        try
        {
                  if (cstmt = null)
                              cstmt.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}

        try
        {
                  if (con = null)
                              con.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
        }
}

    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting, kindly post here.

Comment: just giving user exception message without going yo if or else.

Comment: Surya after `catch(Exception e){`  add `System.out.println("exception "+e.printStackTrace());` will provide details of any exceptions if there are any.

Comment: after adding what u have adviced i got following error while compiling

Comment: An error occurred at line: 72 in the jsp file: /Batch_details_Add1.jsp
The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String, void
69: 
70:        
71:         catch(Exception e){
72:  out.println("exception "+e.printStackTrace());
73:   out.print("<h2 align='center'>course doesn't exist");
74:                 out.println("<center><a href='Addbatch.jsp'>Go Back</a></center>");
75:                 }

Comment: @polppan  is incorrect.    You should use  catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}

Comment: Also please add a finally block and close the connections over there

Comment: @Joe2013 yes you are right, I put wrong syntax. Thanks

Comment: An error occurred at line: 75 in the jsp file: /Batch_details_Add1.jsp
rs cannot be resolved
72:out.println("<center><a href='Addbatch.jsp'>Go Back</a></center>");
73:}
74:finally{
75:rs.close();
76: cstmt.close();
77: con.close();
78: }
An error occurred at line: 76 in the jsp file: /Batch_details_Add1.jsp
cstmt cannot be resolved
73:}
74: finally{
75: rs.close();
76: cstmt.close();
77: con.close();
78: }
79:%>
An error occurred at line: 77 in the jsp file: /Batch_details_Add1.jsp
con cannot be resolved
74: finally{
75: rs.close();
76:      cstmt.close();
77:       con.close();
78: }
79:  %>

Comment: @joe2013 i have made changes to finally block gettin following errors

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 81 in the jsp file: /Batch_details_Add1.jsp
cstmt cannot be resolved to a variable
78:         // conditions PreparedStatements and Connections will always be closed
79:         try
80:         {
81:                   if (cstmt != null)
82:                               cstmt.close();
83:         }
84:         catch(Exception e) {}

Comment: An error occurred at line: 88 in the jsp file: /Batch_details_Add1.jsp
con cannot be resolved to a variable
85: 
86:         try
87:         {
88:                   if (con != null)
89:                               con.close();
90:         }
91:         catch (Exception e){}
An error occurred at line: 89 in the jsp file: /Batch_details_Add1.jsp
con cannot be resolved
86:         try
87:         {
88:                   if (con != null)
89:                               con.close();
90:         }
91:         catch (Exception e){}
92:         }

Comment: There is some syntax error on your code.  Edit your original posting with the latest code.  I still don't see e.printStackTrace() inside ur excpetion block

Comment: @SuryaVaranasi : I doubt you are really having any problem with this. Just look your code carefully. From the errors that you are posting it seems that there is some declaration mistakes.

Comment: @joe2013 i have edited my original post.please have a look

Comment: @ankur.trapasiya i couldn't figureout any declaration mistakes

Comment: @SuryaVaranasi To simplify your code, you could avoid the select query in JSP and do that in your procedure itself. Your procedure can return a value based on successful insertion or if it fails. So you return value from procedure and receive in JSP or Java. Besides you do not need to have `commit' statement in procedure, as you have executeUpdate statement in Java which does that. Regarding the JSP errors, without providing full code it would be difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Seems like your brackets are not correctly closed.  Without the entire code, it is tough to debug

Comment: @Joe2013 here is my entire code

Comment: iam editing my original post

Comment: Put the exception in the post. Remove unrelated markup.

Comment: You have incorrect brackets.  Take a look at once again.  Open in any editor and match the open and close brackets with in the scriplet tag

Comment: i have removed extra brackets.Still it is executing only catch exception block which is incorrect according to my db values.not executing if or else statements

Comment: @SuryaVaranasi If you want to resolve the issue, you have provide what exactly the error you have in catch exception block.

Comment: @Polppan my problem is it is not running if or else statements.i have mba course in course table which references course in batch table.when i am adding mba in batch table it is showing exception error message course doesnt exist which should display when there is no such course in course table.even after its presence in database code is not executing properly.i.e either it should be inserted into database or should give message course and batch already existed.I hope you understood my problem

Answer (score 1):

First modify your procedure as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE udp_addbatch(
    p_batchcode IN VARCHAR2,
    p_ccode     IN VARCHAR2,
    o_var OUT NUMBER )
AS
  v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO v_count
  FROM batches
  WHERE BATCHCODE=p_batchcode
  AND CCODE      =p_ccode;
  IF(v_count < 1 ) THEN
    INSERT INTO BATCHES
      (BATCHCODE,CCODE
      ) VALUES
      (p_batchcode,p_ccode
      );
    o_var := 1;
  ELSE
    o_var := 0;
  END IF;
END ;
-- you can add exception handling
/
```

and in your JSP do as follows, this is not completely tested and it is always better to move Java code out of JSP and have separate class for database connection.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"%>
<html></html>
<html>
        <%@ page import="java.sql.*, java.lang.String"%>
        <head>
                <style type='text/css'>
input{
     FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; FONT-SIZE:10pt; color:blue;
}
body{ 
    FONT-FAMILY:Verdana;
    FONT-SIZE:10pt;
    FONT-WEIGHT:Bold;
    }
table{
    FONT-FAMILY:Verdana;
    FONT-SIZE:10pt;
    FONT-WEIGHT:Bold;
     }
H1,H2,H3{
    FONT-FAMILY:Verdana;
    FONT-SIZE:13pt;
    FONT-WEIGHT:Bold;
    COLOR:BLUE;
    }
SELECT {
        font-family : verdana; font-size : 9pt; background-color : #FCFCFC; border: 1px solid #000000; color:blue;
        } 
TEXTAREA { 
    font-family : verdana; font-size : 9pt; background-color : #FCFCFC; border: 1px solid #000000; color:blue;
        }
</style>
        </head>
        <body bgcolor="white"><%
     // Hope you are getting the connection part  
        Connection con = null; 
        CallableStatement cstmt=null;
        String BatchCode=request.getParameter("BatchCode");
        String CCode=request.getParameter("CCode");

 try {
cstmt=con.prepareCall("{call udp_addbatch(?,?,?)}");
                cstmt.setString(1,BatchCode);
                cstmt.setString(2,CCode);                
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);     
                cstmt.executeUpdate(); 
                int val = cstmt.getInt(3);

       if (val == 1) {
       out.println("<h2 align='center'> Batch and course Successfully added</h2>");
       }
       else {
       out.println("<h2 align='center'> Batch and Course already Exists</h2>");
       // and do your stuff
       }
       }
       catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       }
       finally {
       cstmt.close();
       con.close();
       }

%></body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Popplan thank you .got executed.Now i am able to insert values.